# Testing HashSets in doctest

Tags: testing, hashset, elixir, doctest

I am trying to test HashSet using doctest via iex. If I run the line below, it gives the same result, but the `#HashSet<["rockerboo"]>}` can not be represented in the syntax. I can't think of a way to represent it properly, and I can't find any examples of it. Thanks!

```
  @doc """
  Adds user to HashSet in state

  ## Examples
      iex> Elirc.Channel.add_user_to_state("rockerboo", %{users: HashSet.new})
      %{users: #HashSet<["rockerboo"]>}
  """
  def add_user_to_state(user, state) do
    %{state | users: HashSet.put(state.users, user) }
  end
```

When running `mix test`, I get the following error.

```
 Doctest did not compile, got: (TokenMissingError) lib/elirc/channel.ex:99: missing terminator: } (for "{" starting at line 99)
 code: %{users: #HashSet<["rockerboo"]>}
```

Line 99 is `%{state...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can construct your `HashSet` in a different way so that it's a valid Elixir expression. For example this worked for me:

```
## Examples
  iex> Elirc.Channel.add_user_to_state("rockerboo", %{users: HashSet.new})
  %{users: ["rockerboo"] |> Enum.into(HashSet.new)}
```

This is also the approach that is recommended by the [ExUnit.DocTest documentation](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.0/ex_unit/ExUnit.DocTest.html) under "Opaque Types"

Answer (score 4):

Paweł's answer is correct. Another alternative is to "massage" the data in the doctest. For example, this would work:

```
  iex> state = Elirc.Channel.add_user_to_state("rockerboo", %{users: HashSet.new})
  iex> state.users
  #HashSet<["rockerboo"]>
```

Or:

```
  iex> state = Elirc.Channel.add_user_to_state("rockerboo", %{users: HashSet.new})
  iex> Enum.to_list(state.users)
  ["rockerboo"]
```

I have expanded the doctest section linked by Paweł to include both his and mine examples: https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/64e5f4876007d840edee3040c43e8f98095b8e3d/lib/ex_unit/lib/ex_unit/doc_test.ex#L77

Answer (score 1):

Well your problem is that you are trying to represent something that isn't possible, a HashDict entry with either no key or no value. `HashDict.put(state.users, "rockerboo")` would fail because `put` requires 3 arguments, a HashDict, a key, and a value. Assuming you had something like `name: "rockerboo"` though:

`iex> %{users: Enum.into([name: "rockerboo"], HashDict.new)}
%{users: #HashDict<[name: "rockerboo"]>}`

The above works as expected.

Comment: Well that's what I get for not reading properly, you were using HashSet not HashDict :/. Well I'm leaving it here anyway since it could be helpful for others in a similar situation.

Comment: This answer is actually wrong because the issue is that HashDict is an opaque data  structure and `#HashDict` will always be parsed as a comment.

Comment: @JoséValim Well I pulled this answer basically verbatim from the documentation:

`iex> Enum.into([a: 10, b: 20], HashDict.new)
#HashDict<[b: 20, a: 10]>`

Comment: In the documentation it works fine because the doctest assertion starts with `#HashDict<`. If you put it inside a map, then all bets are off because it is treated as a comment. I have improved the doctest docs to make all this clearer.